# Не получается подключиться с одной виртуальной машины к другой по ssh обе на GNU/Linux debian 12

Tags: linux, debian

Есть 2 ВМ на GNU/Linux Debian 12.
Нaстроены на сети NAT, между собой пингуются.
Пытаюсь создать ssh сервера на обеих и подключиться друг к другу.
При подключении (ssh db-1@ 10.*.*.* -p *****) просит пароль, я его не устанавливал.
Пробовал вводить пароли от обеих учёток , тщетно.

Comment: Строку подключения и полный вывод ошибки

Comment: ssh ddbb1122@10.0.2.15 -p 12344
Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: ddbb1122 пользователь есть на сервере, к которому идет подключение, естественно с паролем?

Comment: Да, пароль "6666" но при вводе его выдаётся та же ошибка...
пароль от пользователя на второй машине "77777777".

Comment: На сервере команда от root что говорит?`journalctl -u ssh.service`

Comment: invalid user ddbb1122 from 10.0.2.7 port 33304 ssh2

Comment: на сервере от root выполнить `useradd usrname` `passwd usrname`  ввести пароль, еще раз попробовать подключиться

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том , что из-за идентичных названий, я пытался подключиться по неверному запросу.

Нужно было писать user@host -p 12344,
Где user - это имя той машины к которой надо было подключиться , а не той , с которой я сейчас подключаюсь.

Очень смеюсь со своей глупости...